# Как узнать код раскладки клавиатуры?

Tags: android, кодировка, utf-8

Нужно создать приложение клавиатуры на ингушском языке. Алфавит в целом латинский, но есть буква состоящая из двух букв.

```
а б в г д е ё ж з и й к л м н о п р с т у ф х ц ч ш щ ъ ы ь э ю я, Ӏ, гӀ, аь, къ, кх, кӀ, тӀ, пӀ, хь, хӀ, чӀ, цӀ, яь
```

Как узнать какой код у этих букв?
Поиска даёт несколько вариантов.
К примеру в поиске показывает что у буквы м код 1052, а статья на Хабре по созданию клавиатуры говорит что код 1082, а как правильно я разобраться не могу и как быть если в одну букву входит две?

Comment: это [диграфы](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84?useskin=vector) , т.е. две буквы, а не один символ. И алфавит в целом кириллический, а не латинский. Т.е. можно ничего не делать, так же как для английских sh, th и т.п. не используются отдельные кнопки, а можно сделать отдельные кнопки, которые будут печатать две буквы сразу. Но придется делать самостоятельно, скорее всего.

Comment: Кстати, в гугл-клавиатуре есть ингушская раскладка

Comment: @Circassian подскажите исходник гугловской клавы?

Comment: а в чем собственно проблема? создаете xml файл там прописывается в атрибутах label (хоть из 10 букв) и code

Comment: @Style-7 так а как узнать какой букве какой код принадлежит?

Comment: Есть оф. руководство как делать клавиатуры да и другие примеры